# Facebook OpenGraph image cropped even with suggested size

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have just added facebook social plugin on my website (http://traveleagle.in) by setting up open graph meta tags. Based on recent guide, I have used a png image in og:image of size 600x315 which translates to recommended aspect ratio of 1.91:1. The problem is that even though the og:image displays correctly using Facebook's lint tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), the image on the sharing plugin appears cropped (154x154). I am meeting the minimum image size criteria yet plugins don't show the complete image and always crop it. Has anyone else had an issue similar to this?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems. Try bigger image: 1146x600 and 1200x630 works for me. Still on some browers it does not fit correctly (like iPhone Safari), but it is a big image.

Comment: Does not provide an answer? Well, it solved the issue for me, then I guess it can work for others too. I think it is an answer.

Comment: My bad. Had not read the question correctly. Deleting the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try [specifying](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices) the width and height:

> Use `og:image:width` and `og:image:height` Open Graph tags. Using these
>   tags will specify the image to the crawler so that it can render it
>   immediately without having to asynchronously.

You can try upsizing that image up to **1200 x 630** so it renders properly on hi-res devices.

Also make sure that on the debugger you are not getting any flags of missing tags. Missing the `fb:app_id` and `og:type` can have unexpected results.

Comment: All of this was done with the page we linked - and it still cropped the bottom and right sides.

Comment: Is the page you linked live so I can have a closer look?

Comment: Yeah, now it is again: http://fachwerkhaus.com/?/60-0-Traumhauswahl.htm (Please note I'm not OP)

Comment: Still having the issue despite this

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a bigger image and then it will be copped to a small size.

As you already know and you have kept the recommended aspect ration andyou have used the following properties as well:

> The og:image property has some optional structured properties:
>
> ```
> og:image:url - Identical to og:image.
> og:image:secure_url - An alternate url to use if the webpage requires HTTPS.
> og:image:type - A MIME type for this image.
> og:image:width - The number of pixels wide.
> og:image:height - The number of pixels high.
> ```

---

You have used a smaller image then FB recommend in the documentation.
Switch to the new size and it will fix your problems (twice as big as the image you used)

> I have used a png image in og:image of size 600x315

### ***`Image Sizes`***

> Use images that are at least **1200 x 630** pixels for the best display on high resolution devices. At the minimum, you should use images that are 600 x 315 pixels to display link page posts with larger images. Images can be up to 8MB in size.

[image]

Comment: Still having the issue despite this